# Error Updating Mysql database via python

Tags: python, mysql

> I am trying to add all words of a text file into a column such that one row has one word. my code is as :

```
 import MySQLdb
 conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = "localhost",user = "root", db = "pcorpora")
 c = conn.cursor()
 file = open('C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\english.txt', 'r')
 words = list(file.read())
 i=0
 for value in words:
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO tenglish (`english words`) VALUES (%s)""" % (words[i]) i=i+1)`
```

The code run without error but table is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use commit

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO tenglish (`english words`) VALUES (%s)""" % (value))
con.commit()
```

> This method sends a `COMMIT` statement to the MySQL server, committing
>   the current transaction. Since by default Connector/Python does not
>   autocommit, it is important to call this method after every
>   transaction that modifies data for tables that use transactional
>   storage engines.

Comment: I again get error it says:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    c.execute('query')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'query' at line 1")

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'query' at line 1"

Comment: What does `i=i+1` mean?